# Why do apps freeze on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, sublime-text

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. I haven't done much to it besides installed Google Chrome, git and sublime text 3.

Multiple apps sometimes become frozen after use. Why?

For example, sometimes after using Firefox (59.0.2) just fine for a while it will suddenly only display the page I'm on with a [Text Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2GCQ.jpg) cursor. Any action attempts (e.g. scrolling, link clicks, highlighting etc.) have no effect. Can't even close the app.

I don't know what brings this behavior about on Firefox but I can consistently repare it on Sublime Text 3 (3143) by launching the app then giving it a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> command. Game over.

Any ideas?

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) has great ideas for an infrequent issue that one could live with. But this is happening many times per day to me, making 18.04 almost unusable. So I need an actual fix. The ideas in that link do not permanently fix my issue.

Here's my hardware: Dell Inspiron, 8GB memory, Intel Core i7-3612QM CPU @ 2.10GHz x 8, Intel Ivybridge Mobile graphics

Comment: Many possible reasons. For example, I noticed more instability after upgrading to 18.04 in my system. However, it had nothing to do with software. Found out that one corner of my CPU cooler had come loose, and even though the temperatures were still manageable (it wasn't anywhere in critical range), instability was much higher as a result. Fixed it, and now everything is stable again.

Comment: @dobey Thanks for the input. The sublime repro case mentioned makes me think it is software related.

Comment: It could still be either. Probably less likely to be an issue with cpu cooler mounting in a laptop, but that is 4 years old, so a possibility, and it could be bad RAM (sublime open dialog could be hitting the specific area of memory that is bad). Unfortunately, this is too broad for the Q&A format of Ask Ubuntu (stack exchange), as it needs plenty of discussion between yourself and those trying to help. The Ubuntu Forums are a better place for such questions. Or Ubuntu Subreddit if you us that.

Comment: I had the same problem and after installed the sublime text following these instructions works fine: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome, I tried this solution, and seemed to work: [Chrome freeze very frequently with ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765974/chrome-freeze-very-frequently-with-ubuntu-16-04). But Sublime Text is still freezing.