# Chrome freezes on freshly installed Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: google-chrome, freeze, 18.10

Note: I already tried all the suggestions from that question, and they didn't help me. [Chrome freeze very frequently with ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765974/chrome-freeze-very-frequently-with-ubuntu-16-04)

I have Ubuntu 18.10 freshly installed on my laptop. Consequently, Google Chrome is also installed from scratch, meaning there are no too many temp files, cached data, etc.
Symptoms: sometimes Chrome freezes only itself, sometimes it freezes the whole Ubuntu UI as well. It lasts from 5 to ~30 seconds and then it unfreezes. It happens only when I browse in Chrome.

How can I figure out what causes the freezes?

Laptop info:

```
Memory: 7.7 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 
Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)
GNOME: 3.30.1
OS type: 64-bit
Disk: 474.9 GB
```

Chrome: `Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: It seems that starting from the Chrome version you mentioned (`71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)`) I have constant crashes of tabs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from 2 settings mentioned in the linked question, I had to disable two more flags, which helped me, but not completely. All the settings I changed:

```
Use hardware acceleration when available = Off
GPU rasterization = Disabled
Accelerated 2D canvas = Disabled
Out of process rasterization = Disabled
```

**UPD**. Well, after a couple of days testing, the changes above haven't helped get rid of freezes completely, but reduced them significantly. Chrome still freezes, but less often, and if it does, it does it only itself without freezing the whole Ubuntu.